# Check for optionally targets in cmake that are not in the correct order

Tags: c++, cmake

i'm currently working on a large software project which uses cmake as build system. But i have a problem to check if another target exists (or will exist).

For example there is root CMakeLists.txt and two modules that can optionally added to the software project as subfolders.

```
.
├── A
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── B
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

In the root CMakeLists these modules are added with the add_subdirectory command:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11 FATAL_ERROR)
project(root)
add_subdirectory(./A)
add_subdirectory(./B)
```

In some cases i want to check in module A if module B exists and add an define to the compile options in module A:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11 FATAL_ERROR)
project(A)
add_libary(A a.cpp a.hpp)
if (TARGET B)
    target_compile_definitions(A PUBLIC HAVE_B)
endif()
```

The

```
if(TARGET target-name)
```

command will return false because this will only work if the modules are added in the right order to the root CMakeLists.txt.

Is there another check in cmake that doesn't depend on the order of the targets?

Greetings
Perry

Comment: CMake process configuration stage in order. So, when `A/CMakeLists.txt` is processing, CMake has no information, whether `B/CMakeLists.txt` will be processed or not. It is problem of the modules integrator to enumerate them in correct order.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While I was writing an answer on how to handle your CMake problem, I was thinking that there is probably an C++ solution for your problem. Could one solution be the use of the [dependency injection pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)? Something with an `#ifdef HAVE_B` check in it may be more difficult to unit test then something using interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using a macro.

The idea is that each subdirectory must have an associated top-level variable that other subdirectories can check, so they must be declared on the top CMakeLists.txt file. Also all variables must be defined before the start of the `add_subdirectory` rules.

So our macro will take as parameters the list of subdirectories, first output the list of variable declarations, and then output the list of subdirectories.

Here is the code for such a macro:

```
macro(declare_modules)
    foreach(module ${ARGN})
        set(TARGET_${module} yes)
    endforeach()

    foreach(module ${ARGN})
        add_subdirectory(./${module})
    endforeach()
endmacro(declare_modules)
```

It can be used like this:

```
declare_modules(A B C)
```

And it will expand into the following code:

```
foreach(module A B C)
    set(TARGET_${module} yes)
endforeach()

foreach(module A B C)
    add_subdirectory(./${module})
endforeach()
```

This will result into the variables `TARGET_A`, `TARGET_B`, and `TARGET_C` to be declared and set to yes, and they will be available from all modules.

Adding new modules is just a matter of adding new parameters to the `declare_modules` call.

Answer (score 1):

Because the root `CMakeLists.txt` file have to know the project's subdirectories, I normally put my optional settings there:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11 FATAL_ERROR)

project(root CXX)

if (EXISTS "B/CMakeLists.txt")
    set(HAVE_B 1)
endif()

add_subdirectory(A)
if (HAVE_B)
    add_subdirectory(B)
endif()
```

**A/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(A a.cpp a.hpp)
if (HAVE_B)
    target_link_libraries(A B)
endif()
```

**B/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(B b.cpp b.hpp)
target_compile_definitions(B PUBLIC HAVE_B)
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC .)
```

There are a lot of possibile places you could set the compiler definitions and necessary include directories. In this example I've choosen to propagade both with [`target_compile_definitions(... PUBLIC ...)`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_compile_definitions.html) and [`target_include_directories(... PUBLIC ...)`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_include_directories.html). Then you just have to setup the dependency with [`target_link_libraries()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_link_libraries.html) and CMake handles the rest (and `target_link_libraries()` does accept forward declarations).

Answer (score 0):

There is no available `$<TARGET_EXISTS:...>` generator expression where you could write this:

```
add_libary(A a.cpp a.hpp)
target_compile_definitions(A PUBLIC $<<TARGET_EXISTS:B>:HAVE_B=1>)
```

Although I am proposing this to cmake, [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17123). As a workaround, you can create shadow targets to track the targets from other directories:

```
# Custom property to check if target exists
define_property(TARGET PROPERTY "INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS"
    BRIEF_DOCS "True if target exists"
    FULL_DOCS "True if target exists"
)

# Create shadow target to notify that the target exists
macro(shadow_notify TARGET)
    if(NOT TARGET _shadow_target_${TARGET})
        add_library(_shadow_target_${TARGET} INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
    endif()
    set_target_properties(_shadow_target_${TARGET} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS 1)
endmacro()
# Check if target exists by querying the shadow target
macro(shadow_exists OUT TARGET)
    if(NOT TARGET _shadow_target_${TARGET})
        add_library(_shadow_target_${TARGET} INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
        set_target_properties(_shadow_target_${TARGET} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS 0)
    endif()
    set(${OUT} "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:_shadow_target_${TARGET},INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS>")
endmacro()
```

This creates two functions, and a custom property to track if the target exists or not. The `shadow_notify` will create a shadow target if it doesn't exists and then set the `INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS` property to true if it does exists.

The `shadow_exists` target will create a generator expression to query if the target exists. It does this by creating a new shadow target if doesn't exists with the `INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS` property set to 0. Then it will create a generator expression that will query the `INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS` property on the shadow target. The shadow target will always exists, and if the actual target exists then the property will be set to 1 by `shadow_notify`.

So then you can write this in your cmake:

```
add_libary(A a.cpp a.hpp)
# Notify that target A exists
shadow_notify(A)
# Check if target B exists
shadow_exists(HAS_B B)
target_compile_definitions(A PUBLIC $<${HAS_B}:HAVE_B=1>)
```

When you create library `B` you will need to call `shadow_notify(B)` as well.

If you don't like these extra `shadow_notify` calls, you could also override `add_library` to do it for you:

```
macro(add_library LIB)
    _add_library(${LIB} ${ARGN})
    if(NOT TARGET _shadow_target_${TARGET})
        _add_library(_shadow_target_${TARGET} INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
    endif()
    set_target_properties(_shadow_target_${TARGET} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_TARGET_EXISTS 1)
endmacro()
```