# CMake scoping rules

Tags: cmake

I am a bit confused about scoping rules of cmake.
I do have files and directories like

```
 ├── test
 │    CMakeLists.txt 
 │   ├── cmake
 │   │       MyCMake 
 │   │       MyCMake2 
 │   ├── child
 │   │       CMakeLists.txt
```

The contents are:

cmake/MyCMake:

```
set(MY_NAME MyName)
message("MyCMake: " ${MY_NAME} " " ${YOUR_NAME} " " ${HIS_NAME})
```

cmake/MyCMake2:

```
set(HIS_NAME NewName)
message("MyCMake2: " ${MY_NAME} " " ${YOUR_NAME} " " ${HIS_NAME})
```

child/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(YOUR_NAME YourName)
set(HIS_NAME HisName PARENT_SCOPE)
message("Child: " ${MY_NAME} " " ${YOUR_NAME} " " ${HIS_NAME})
```

test/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
include(MyCMake)
add_subdirectory(child)
message("Parent1: " ${MY_NAME} " " ${YOUR_NAME} " " ${HIS_NAME})
include(MyCMake2)
message("Parent2: " ${MY_NAME} " " ${YOUR_NAME} " " ${HIS_NAME})
```

The result is

```
MyCMake: MyName  
Child: MyName YourName 
Parent1: MyName  HisName
MyCMake2: MyName  NewName
Parent2: MyName  NewName
```

This first line is OK, the 2nd and third variables are not yet defined.
With the second line, it looks like it is a parent-only setting, i.e. the defined variable has a scope ONLY in the parent. (So, I can/shall the same variable with local scope?) The third line shows only variable with parent scope, OK. The 4th line shows that I set a LOCAL scope variable. In the 5th line, however, I see that the PARENT scope value has changed, which I expected to be changed ONLY locally, in the child subdirectory. 
What is going on here? (it looks like I can overwrite a value of the variable, which is not in my scope)

Why I started to experiment: under some conditions I do not see in the parent directory the variables (like include directories, library names, etc.) defined in the child directory. Is there a standard way to use say a library name for building in one child, and use the same name in another child for linking?

Also a question: I have an application, consisting of a library and an executable. It looks like that CMake does not allow to use the same target name for both. In my eyes, if I use name 'A' both for binary target and library target, it should not result in confusion, because the real second target is 'libA'. Am I wrong?

Comment: For the first question see [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882). For your second question I suppose you are searching for [Check for optionally targets in cmake that are not in the correct order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766151). For your third question you may want to take a look at [add_custom_command is not generating a target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719275)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The basic rule is simple: `add_subdirectory` establishes a new scope, `include` does *not.* So your example has just two scopes involved:

- The scope of the top-level CMakeList, which is affected by the `set(...)` commands in `MyCMake` and `MyCMake2`, and by the `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)` command inside `child/CMakeLists.txt`.
- The scope of the child CMakeList `child/CMakeLists.txt`, which is affected by the `set(...)` commands inside `child/CMakeLists.txt` which do not use `PARENT_SCOPE`.

You are correct that `PARENT_SCOPE` sets the value in the parent scope *only.* If you want to set the value both for the current scope and for the parent, you have to issue two `set` commands:

```
set(var Value)
set(var Value PARENT_SCOPE)
```

---

We generally prefer one question per question here on Stack Overflow, but I will answer the target naming question as well: CMake target names are logical names of the targets for CMake, and they have to be unique. Imagine if that was not the case:

```
add_library(L STATIC ...)
add_library(A SHARED ...)
add_executable(A ...)

target_link_libraries(A L)
```

What would be the effect of the last line? Would the library `A` link against `L`, or would the executable `A` do so? Or both? Dtto for setting properties etc.

You can control the name of the produced binary independently from its target name: refer to target properties like [`OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) for details.

Comment: Basically, I agree with the "one question per question" rule, but this time the three  questions are interrelated and the mandatory delay between questions means I need 4.5 hours to post three questions. Concerning the logical names: you are right, but this scheme prevents to create a binary with name A using library libA.

Comment: @katang No, it does not prevent the binary-library scheme at all. You just give the targets logical names `A_bin` and `A_lib`, and set both of their `OUTPUT_NAME` properties to `A`. *Nothing* prevents you from doing that.